# Updating columns of Excel 2019 using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I found this VBA code which presently fills cols E and F with Date/Time and updates col F only with Date/Time when it detects a change in the range A2:D50. It works beautifully and thanks to the author. 
What I'd like to do is:

- to fill col E if there's a change in range B2:B50.
- and fill col F if there's a change in range D2:D50.

I tried to modify the code and could fill col E, but am unable to update col F.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Timestamp Data
    '   TeachExcel.com - Original Author

    Dim myTableRange As Range
    Dim myDateTimeRange As Range
    Dim myUpdatedRange As Range

    'Your data table range
    Set myTableRange = Range("A2:D50")

    'Check if the changed cell is in the data tabe or not.
    If Intersect(Target, myTableRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'Stop events from running
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Column for the date/time
    Set myDateTimeRange = Range("E" & Target.Row)
    'Column for last updated date/time
    Set myUpdatedRange = Range("F" & Target.Row)

    'Determine if the input date/time should change
    If myDateTimeRange.Value = "" Then   
        myDateTimeRange.Value = Now 
    End If

    'Update the updated date/time value
    myUpdatedRange.Value = Now

    'Turn events back on
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Set `myTableRange` to `B2:B50`. Then change your `IF` statement to: `If Not Intersect(Target, myTableRange) Is Nothing Then`. If `Target` is in range, perform your steps. If `Target` is not in that range, reset `myTableRange` to `D2:D50` in an `Else`. Then check if your `Target` is in that range. If it is, perform your steps

Comment: @ZAC - Thanks I'll try

Comment: @ZAC Ok tried and succeeded, thank you

Comment: No problem, glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

Set `myTableRange` to `B2:B50`. Then change your `IF` statement to: `If Not Intersect(Target, myTableRange) Is Nothing Then`. If `Target` is in range, perform your steps. If `Target` is not in that range, reset `myTableRange` to `D2:D50` in an `Else`. Then check if your `Target` is in that range. If it is, perform your steps